# I am unable to display the data in Address column in excel sheet

Tags: php, excel, elgg

I need to display the complete address details in Address column, but I am displayed like this:

[image: Please click on image].

Can you please help me? How to solved the issue.

```
<?php $users = elgg_get_entities(array( 'type' => 'user', 'limit' => 9999)); $data = array(); foreach($users as $euser){
if($euser->banned == "no" && $euser->enabled == "yes") {
if(!$euser->ext_mod){
    $user = new SsportalUser($euser);
$row = array();
$row['Address'] = $user->basic('address');
array_push($data, $row);
} } }function cleanData(&$str) {
$str = preg_replace('/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/', '', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/\s/u', '', $str);
$str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"'; } header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=active_users_list.xls");header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel"); $flag = false;foreach($data as $row) {if(!$flag) {
    echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
    $flag = true;
}
    array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
    echo implode("\t",array_values($row))."\r\n";
}exit;
```

Comment: What is your input? How did you import your data? Is it csv you open with Excel? Probably your import format is wrong, but what is it?

Comment: Thank you for giving reply to me, This is the code to display the address data. Can you please check that code in given below.

Comment: Just now i posted my code. Please check it once sir.

Comment: Great, this should allow the community to help you (I have no php instance myself to try anything).

Comment: Thank you very much sir, for giving reply to me.

Comment: Could you post what format the source data is in? It may be something as simple as parsing commas

Comment: can you click on  above link i.e, " Please click on image" . You can able to view the format of the data. Thank you sir.